# C# - Issues Copy/Pasting in Tasks

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, selenium-chromedriver

I've recently come to like using tasks over creating a thread and joining it. It has solved a few issues, running multiple single thread methods running at the same time. Below is Method 1 (My old version) & Method 2 (testing current version).

(See Below)

Method 1:

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "123" && comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() == "XYZ")
{
    Thread dgnsi = new Thread(DG_NSI);          // Kick off a new thread
    dgnsi.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    dgnsi.IsBackground = false;
    b_run.Enabled = true;
    dgnsi.Start();
}
```

Method 2:

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "123" && comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() == "XYZ")
{
    Task dgnsi = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        DG_NSI();
    });
}
```

Start of Thread:

```
[STAThread]
private void DG_NSI()
{
    var timespan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(4);
    var driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
    driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
    using (IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(driverService, new ChromeOptions()))
    {
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(timespan);
        string _pa = tb_payagreement.Text;
        string _noa = noa;
        string _si = si;

        //Add Pay Agreement
        IWebElement pa_I = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/form/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[@id='tab'][2]/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table[@class='Ntexteleftalignnowrapnoborder']/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/textarea[@class='textarea']"));
        pa_I.Click();
        Clipboard.Clear();  // Always clear the clipboard first
        Clipboard.SetText(_pa);
        SendKeys.SendWait("^v");

        //Add Nature of activity
        IWebElement noa_I = driver.FindElement(By.Name("woNOA"));
        noa_I.Click();
        Clipboard.Clear();  // Always clear the clipboard first
        Clipboard.SetText(_noa);
        SendKeys.SendWait("^v");

        //Add Special Instructions
        IWebElement si_I = driver.FindElement(By.Name("woSI"));
        si_I.Click();
        Clipboard.Clear();  // Always clear the clipboard first
        Clipboard.SetText(_si);
        SendKeys.SendWait("^v");

        //Close Application
        driver.Quit();
    }
} //Complete
```

To explain what I'm trying to achieve, I'm trying to be able to use selenium to automate tasks for myself with the click of a Winforms button. Currently I have multiple threads setup same as above. One of my issues from going from Method 1 -> Method 2 was that everything was working fine up until copying/pasting the information from a string and pasting it. It simply would not paste anything and finish the task all the way through. Anyone have any insight on how to paste information inside a task or an alternative?

(Note: I've tried sendkeys but its too slow. Also this is a simplified version of code.)

Comment: all that repeated clipboard code should probably go in a method that takes `ChromeDriver`, `string`, and `By` arguments...

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try when I get home

Comment: @ Rufus L Tried the following in a separate method. I'm fairly new with using seperate methods to clear redundancy. However, this method did not work and still skipped over the pasting process.                                                    `publicvoid CopyPaste(string copy,IWebElement element)
        {
            Clipboard.Clear();  // Always clear the clipboard first
            Clipboard.SetText(copy);
            element.Click();
            SendKeys.SendWait("^v");
        }`